# Execute php code once a week, but random day

Tags: php, mysql, random

I'm working on a PHP promotion campaign with discounts for stores stored in a DB. Once a week, random day and time within this week, I need to run an sql query and show a discount coupon.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
if(once_a_week()){
show_discount_coupon();
}
```

This is getting harder than I thought, any suggestions on how to face this problem?

Comment: just run the script manually every week when you feel like it, that should give you absolute randomness

Comment: @NiftyDude: Taking normal sleeping hours into account, it wouldn't really be "absolute" radnomness. ;)

Comment: What's granularity of the time frame for showing the coupon? Shall the coupon be shown from that time until the end of the week or only for a specific time span?

Comment: @Paul not sure what sleeping hours got to do with randomness :o

Comment: Since you suggested running it "manually", I am sure he will loose all the hours while he is in bed. ;) That way, it won't be random throughout the whole week (all 168 hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generate random dates and times for every week in a database, and then check it in your website's code. Get the first date out of your list of dates from the database, and test it:

```
if $date_today == $next_coupon_date{ showCoupon(); }
```

After that week, you delete this date, and you'll be using the next one in line. :)

That way, once the dates are created, you'll never have to worry about anything again.

Comment: No need to manually delete the date once it's past. Just create a table with one record for each week of the year, and in that record have a randomly selected time. The script can check for which week it is, pull the corresponding time, and display the coupon if it's within a certain number of hours of that time.

Comment: Thanks, I think this should do it

Answer (score 0):

I found a really quick and dirty way to do exactly what you want, but it's not very secure:

[Link (it's in the third response)](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3875021.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create in your database, or config file , two fields ex. "next_week_day","update_time";
2. In your script generate the value for field,

   $next_week_day = rand(1,7);

3.Check the day in your script:

```
<?php
  if(date("N") == $next_week_day){
      show_discount_cuppon();
      if($update_time<time()){
         $update_time = time();
      }
    $next_week_day = rand(1,7);
  }
?>
```